# Currying a flipped function using lodash - Are there limitations?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I'm new to lodash and just playing around with it to become familiar.
I'm trying to curry a flipped function and I'm getting a TypeError.

Currying the same 'unflipped' function works as expected.

```
const curriedMap = _.curry(_.map);
const squares1 = curriedMap([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]);

console.log(squares1(x => x * x)); // [ 1, 4, 9, 16 ]


const flippedMap = _.flip(_.map);

console.log(flippedMap(x => x * x, [1, 2, 3, 4])); // [ 1, 4, 9, 16 ]

const curriedFlippedMap = _.curry(flippedMap);

const makeSquares = curriedFlippedMap(x => x * x);

console.log(makeSquares([1, 2, 3, 4])); // TypeError: makeSquares is not a function
```

I'm expecting the last line to produce `[ 1, 4, 9, 16 ]`, but instead I get 'TypeError'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`_.map` has a length property (number of parameters) that `_.curry` can use to curry it automatically, but `_.flip(_.map)` can’t easily produce a new function with the same length as its input (it reverses the entire argument list, it’s not just `f => (a, b) => f(b, a)`).

```
> _.map.length
2

> _.flip(_.map).length
0
```

`_.curry` lets you [specify the number of parameters](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#curry) to work around that:

```
const curriedFlippedMap = _.curry(flippedMap, 2);
```